# Add child element based on directive and recompile?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's say my HTML is like:

```
<body myDirective ng-controller="ContentCtrl">
    <section id="content">

    </section>
    <footer ng-controller="FooterCtrl" myFooterDirective>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="btn_home"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

How can I set `myDirective` to change the `<footer>` element so that it has an extra child element? like:

```
    <footer ng-controller="FooterCtrl" myFooterDirective>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="btn_home"></div>
            <div id="customAddedChild"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

and should I use `myFooterDirective` or `FooterCtrl` ? or neither, and just search for `elem.find('toolbar')` or similar?

**EDIT:**
Here's what the toolbar code actually contains by default, I would need to change it for only 1 project which is set as the myDirective (in face for each project I do: projectProjectName and I also set myApp.value('project', ProjectName); etc.

```
<div id="toolbar">
    <button id="btn_home" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 50px" ng-click="goHome('<?=$this->url('application/default', ['project' => $this->project])?>')">
        <div class="btn_img" style="background-image: url('/images/home.png')"></div>
    </button>

    <button id="btn_back" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 50px; display: none" ng-click="goBack()">
        <div class="btn_img" style="background-image: url('/images/back.png')"></div>
    </button>

    <?php if (count($this->config['langs']) > 1):?>
        <?php $i = 0;?>
        <?php foreach ($this->config['langs'] as $lang):?>
            <?php
            $flag = $lang;
            switch ($lang) {
                case 'en':
                    $flag = 'gb';
                    break;
            }
            ?>
            <div class="flag-button pull-right" <?php echo $i == 0 ? 'style="margin-right:50px"' : null?>>
                <a href="<?=$this->url('application/default', ['project' => $this->project], ['query' => ['lang' => $lang]])?>">
                    <div class="flag-icon-background flag-icon-<?=$flag?> flag"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <?php $i++;?>
        <?php endforeach?>
    <?php endif?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real and correct angular approach would be the use of a directive for the footer, with a simple ng-repeat for your elements. The element list would be initialized by the directive.

Aka :

```
 <footer my-footer-directive>
    <div id="toolbar">
        <div ng-repeat="footerEl in footerElements" id="footerEl.id" ng-click="footeEl.action()"></div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

with the directive :

```
module.directive("myFooterDirective", function() {
return {
    restrict : "A",
    scope : true,
    link : function($scope, $el, $attrs) {
        $scope.footerElements = [
            {
                id : "btn_home",
                action : function() {
                    // do something
                }
            }
        ];
        // insert other elements here depending on you needs and/or app logic
    }
}
```

});

Of course, this requires that every elements has the same html representation / that the elements can be represented programmatically.

The dirty approach would be :

```
 <footer my-footer-directive>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="btn_home"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

And

```
module.directive("myFooterDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        scope : true,
        link : function($scope, $el, $attrs) {
            var myDirtyInjectedDomElement = $("<i-am-ugly/>");
            // maybe compile it here if this is not only an ugly html but an ugly dynamic element, see $compile if needed
            $el.find("#toolbar").append(myDirtyInjectedDomElement);
        }
    }
});
```

EDIT due to comment :

Here is how it comes for only one optional element, with ng-if :

```
 <footer my-footer-directive>
        <div id="toolbar">
            <div id="btn_home"></div>
             <div id="my_optional_element" ng-if="showTheOptional"></div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

And

```
module.directive("myFooterDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        scope : true,
        link : function($scope, $el, $attrs) {
           $scope.showTheOptional = true; // or false, or 42
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, ok so for the 'right' way - how would I re-create the PHP loop or can I leave it in and just do the loop for the other buttons? - I would then need to figure out how I can run the loop 'by default' for all projects but override the loop from another project (which is defined in the <body myDirective>)

Comment: As basically what I need to do is just add 1 extra div element e.g.: <div myProjectNameFooterDirective></div> so I'm thinking it might be easier to do it the dirty way :/ but would prefer to do it cleanly...

Comment: if you only have ONE element, then use a ng-if in the template, and init the value of the ng-if condition in the directive. This would be the prettiest way. Edited my answer to show the example

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot! Using ng-if and then a directive like: <div ng-if="showTheOptional" ng-myDirective> works nice